# updating embedded document not working mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The Collection contains the following entry

```
> db.tags.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5446a012cdc70d0732565c84"), "tag" : "java", "data" : [ { "date" : "2001/1/20", "view" : "700" } ], "__v" : 0 }
```

When i try to push the data into the array using the following code

```
var Tag =  require('./DBConn');
var condtion = {"_id" : "5446a012cdc70d0732565c84"}
var updateData ={  
           "data":[  
              {  
                   "date":"2001/1/21",
                   "view":"145"

              }
           ]

}
tag.update(condtion,{$push:updateData},function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('Update Success!');

});
```

and query the collection, it gives the same records, without updating the collection,

```
> db.tags.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5446a012cdc70d0732565c84"), "tag" : "java", "data" : [ { "date" : "2001/1/20", "view" : "700" } ], "__v" : 0 }
```

What wrong i'm doing in the update, where to correct this ?

Added complete Code

**The ModelT.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/stack1');


var stackSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
})

var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var tagData = new Schema(
{
    tag  : String,
    data :[viewData]
}
    )
var viewData = new Schema({
    view     : String,
    date      : Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tag', tagData);
```

**The Test.js file**

```
   var Tag =  require('./ModelT');
var condtion = {"_id" : "5446acd5277da1896bb326a6"}
var updateData = {
          "data": {  
            "date":"2001/1/21",
            "view":"145"
          }
        };

//var updateData = {
//        "data": { $each: [{
//          "date":"2001/1/21",
//          "view":"145"
//        }]}
//      };
var tag = new Tag(

);
Tag.update(condtion,{$push:updateData},function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('Update Success!');

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing an array of values to a `$push` operator, you need to use the [`$each`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) modifier:

```
var updateData = {
  "data": { $each: [{
    "date":"2001/1/21",
    "view":"145"
  }]}
};
```

Either that or just pass the single object without putting it in an array:

```
var updateData = {
  "data": {  
    "date":"2001/1/21",
    "view":"145"
  }
};

tag.update(condtion, {$push: updateData}, function (err) {
  if (!err) console.log('Update Success!');
});
```